# golang Gorp Postgres select return only one row

Tags: postgresql, go, gorp

I just started go programming.

In Go, I used gorp.v1 with lib pq, since my database is Postgres.
I have written a Postgres function and call it from gorp and libpq. 
The function returns multiple rows. But when I call it from grop dbmap it returns only one row.

Below is the code sample:

```
rowData := []*RoadData{}

_, err := db.PgMap.Select(&rowData, "SELECT * FROM pgr_roadDataCost(1000, 'roadnetwork',lattitidue1,logitude1,lattitidue2,logitude2)")
```

When I print `rowData`, it contains only one row, but actually there are multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SelectOne method :

```
var roadData RoadData
err := db.PgMap.SelectOne(&roadData, "SELECT * FROM pgr_roadDataCost(1000, 'roadnetwork',lattitidue1,logitude1,lattitidue2,logitude2)")
```

Comment: Actually I want to get all the rows, but in my way it returns only one row. When I used gorp for MySql in the same way it returns all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

If your query returns only one row, you can use db.QueryRow:

`db.QueryRow("select name from users where id = ?", 1).Scan(&name)`

You [can read here for more details](http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html).